# Can't set Html.HiddenFor value attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, mvc-editor-templates, html.hiddenfor

I'm trying to make a custom create form using an Editor Template and Entity Framework.  The problem I'm having is that all of my fields show up with no value attribute set.  This throws an error in the ModelState when dealing with the hidden key value because it essentially has no value.  Here's an example of what I'm doing.

**Car.cs**

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int CarID{ get; set; }

    [required]
    public string Make { get; set; }

    [required]
    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    [required]
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

**Car.cshtml** (Editor Template)

```
@model Car

@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.CarID, new { Value = "0" })
@Html.EditorFor(c => c.Make)
@Html.EditorFor(c => c.ModelName)
@Html.EditorFor(c => c.Year)
```

**CreateCar.cshtml** (View)

```
@model Car

<form id="create-car-form" method="post">
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <a onclick="SubmitForm()">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Now this is only an example.  I'm actually submitting my form through an ajax call to avoid reloading the page and I'm setting up dropdowns for Make and ModelName in my editor template.  However I'm able to get all the information ok in my controller action as long as it's been entered in the form.

If a field is left blank then the ModelState gets an error because a value was empty when it expected some value.  This is particularly a problem with hidden fields as it cannot receive a value from the user, Nor do I want it to.

Further exploration shows that the Html generated for the fields all have an empty 'value' attribute.  And by that I mean that the input tag looks something like this in the inspector:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The CarID field is required." id="CarID" name="CarID" type="hidden" value>
```

However copying the element from the inspector and pasting it gives this:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The CarID field is required." id="CarID" name="CarID" type="hidden" value="">
```

This is obviously my culprit but I can't understand why the value attribute is not getting set when I specify it in the editor template.

**EDIT**
**CarsView.cshtml**

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("CreateCar", new Car());
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function SubmitForm() {
    var form = $('#create-car-form');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/CreateCar",
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(form.serialize();
        }
    });
}
```

The console log will reveal that `form.serialize()` returns the following string:

```
"CarID=&ModelName=Camry&Make=Toyota&Year=2010"
```

This shows that there is no value for CarID.  This is also the only JS that I've used thus far for the application and it occurs after the form has already been setup which is why I believe something strange is happening with the Html helpers.

Comment: You never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. The methods already do that correctly by first using `ModelState` values if they exist, then from `ViewData` and finally from the property value.

Comment: Except that it doesn't set a value for the int even without me trying to set the Value attribute there.  Hence why I felt the need to put it in in the first place.

Comment: It will correctly set based on the code you have shown. I can only assume you have other code which is causing the issue (the only way you could get `value=""` is if the property were `int?` (nullable) and its value was `null` when you passed the model to the view.

Comment: I can confirm that the property is not `int?` and the value is never being set.  I have other models whose properties are setup the same and don't have this problem.  Only difference is that I don't use an editor template for them. However I have tried this model without an editor template and it still has the problem.

Comment: It can only be a result of some other code which you have not shown us (perhaps some javascript)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem exists before javascript but I will update to give more explanation to what that part looks like.

Comment: Did you tried: `@Html.Partial("CreateCar", new Car { CarID = 2 });`? Also by using `@Html.HiddenFor(...)` the value is automatically set.

Comment: Change this line `public int CarID{ get; set; }` to `public int CarID{ get; set; } = 0`, then change this line `@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.CarID, new { Value = "0" })` to `@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.CarID)`. I'm figuring that it's probably not setting the value attribute since `value = default(int)` is true.